# Recent comprehensive text-books on machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, books

I would like to ask what are the current recommendations for professional and comprehensive, current books on machine learning.

The two quite classic comprehensive text-books are:

- Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective (Murphy, 2012)
- The Elements of Statistical Learning: Data Mining, Inference, and Prediction (By Springer Statistics, 2009)

But they are somewhat dated, so I wonder if there are more recent choices? You may also recommend books that focus on sub-sections of ML, or anything that is recent and of note.

Comment: Please comment why the downvotes?

Answer (score 4):

There are (at least) two recent and comprehensive ML books:

1. [**Probabilistic Machine Learning: An Introduction**](https://probml.github.io/pml-book/book1.html) by Kevin Murphy.
2. **[Hands-on Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras, and TensorFlow](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/hands-on-machine-learning/9781492032632/)** by Aurélien Géron

Both authors provide draft/raw versions for free online. The latter one however, as title already indicates, does not provide the same mathematical depth as the books by Kevin Murphy or Hastie et al.

Comment: I am not really looking for "introduction" type book, but thanks for the recommendation. I will definitely check it out. Do you think machine learning is moving more to Python from R?

Comment: @Dole If you're interested in ML then there's currently no way around Python. Specifically, when it comes to Deep Learning, as an essential sub field and highly active area of research of ML.

Comment: Interesting, I thought R was more popular in the past, but Python is getting more popular...

Answer (score 2):

### Machine learning theory

- [Foundations of Machine Learning](http://Foundations%20of%20Machine%20Learning), 2018
- [Pattern recognition by C. Bishop](https://www.springer.com/jp/book/9780387310732), 2006

### Practical approach

- [Machine Learning engineering](http://www.mlebook.com/wiki/doku.php)

### Specific field

- [Interpretable Machine Learning, C. Molnar](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/)

### With focus on deep learning

- [Dive into Deep Learning. It is an interactive book with lot of code examples](https://d2l.ai/)
- [Deep Learning book](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/)